# How to add Two number in simple intent DialogFlow?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to add two numbers using DialogFlow. 
Question: Add 5 and 6
My Ans: Result is 5+6
[image]

but I'm getting the response this one.

Ans Logic: Result is $number + $number1

Answer (score 0):

> https://discuss.api.ai/t/start-conversation-with-user-programatically-from-the-server-side-api-ais-side-on-a-notification/1876/2
>
> It’s an API for creating a Natural Language Understanding model for a
> conversational interface. If you have custom business logic or
> platform-specific message formatting requirements then

for that you will need to turn on fulfillment and in that part get the parameters that was recognised in `action and parameters` using `queryResult.parameters.<nameofparam>` and do your task like

```
let num1 = parseInt(queryResult.parameters.number);
let num2 = parseInt(queryResult.parameters.number1);
let responseText =  {
    "fulfillmentText": "",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [],
    "source": "example.com",
    "payload": {},
    "outputContexts": [],
    "followupEventInput": {}
};
responseText.fulfillmentText = "" + num1 + num2;
res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(responseText));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform some operations, then you need to make use of fulfillment - webhook concept. I used Django framework to capture the request and sent back the response as jsonresponse.

**Below is the piece of code:**

```
@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
  # build a request object
  req = json.loads(request.body)
  # get action from json (i.e) arithmetic operation that we need to perform
  action = req.get('queryResult').get('action')
  #get the numbers from the json
  num = req.get('queryResult').get('parameters')
  n1 = int(num.get('number'))
  n2 = int(num.get('number1'))
  if action == 'addition':
  # return a fulfillment message
      fulfillmentText = {'fulfillmentText': n1+n2}
return JsonResponse(fulfillmentText, safe=False)
```

If you are interested to know more, please spend sometime in reading [my blog](https://medium.com/@mksiddhu2/calculator-chatbot-dialo-e9f8e08d07af) which has the complete piece of code along with steps of implementation.